# How to make a picture work as a background with a blur filter

Tags: html, css

I wanna use an image on my site as a brackground with a blur filter.

I tried using this in a css file:

```
.bg-image{
    background-image: url("../store/groupLK.jpg");
    filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and in the html file:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg-image">
/* the rest of the code including some other images */
</div>
</body>
```

And it seems to work but it blurs all of the images that I use as well instead of "groupLK.jpg" only. I also tried using the class bg-image before/after the other pictures but it only appears in that position and not in the rest of the site. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try `background-attachment: fixed` ?

Comment: I just did, same results. Thank you though

Comment: Did you have any other element having class name as `bg-image` ?

Comment: No, this is the only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because blur filter is applied to the parent and therefor also effects all its children.

You could wrap your image and the text (or other images) in a container:

```css
.bg-image{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/200x200");
  filter: blur(2px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-image">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Hallo
  </div>
</div>
```